# explain the solution and/or suggest a different one

Tags: limits, reference-request, improper-integrals

I have come across the following problem, in my calculus II course, about improper integrals:

**problem:**
*Find the following limit, if it exists.*

### $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1} \int\limits_{x}^{x^2} \! \bigg\{ \frac{1}{\log(t)}-\frac{1}{t\log(t)} \bigg\} \, \mathrm{d}t$

$\log(t)$ *is the natural logarithm of $t$.*

The suggested solution is the above:

**solution:** *Since* $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to 1} \bigg\{ \frac{1}{\log(t)}-\frac{1}{t\log(t)} \bigg\}= \cdots= 1$, *we get that* $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1} \int\limits_{x}^{x^2} \! \bigg\{ \frac{1}{\log(t)}-\frac{1}{t\log(t)} \bigg\} \, \mathrm{d}t = 0$

I am having a hard time understanding the solution.
What is the thoughts that lead as to calculate the $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to 1} \bigg\{ \frac{1}{\log(t)}-\frac{1}{t\log(t)} \bigg\}$? 
Should we consider the fact that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1} x =\lim_{x\to 1} x^2 =1$? Is this approach suitable for another problem? Is there any other approach?

Moreover i would like to see more examples, texts on improper integrals with variable bounds, and limits with improper integrals, if there are any.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I edited a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit calculation shows that the integrand is bounded close to $1$. And the integral is now an integral of a bounded function over an interval whose length tends to zero. Thus, the limit is zero. Try go convince yourself that this is true 1) by drawing a graph and 2) by completing the argument with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ if that is what you are into...

Comment: what if the function inside the integral wasn't bounded?

Comment: Then the integral is "improper", and one has to check more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{t\to 1}\dfrac{1}{\ln{t}}-\dfrac{1}{t\ln{t}}=\lim_{t\to 1}\dfrac{t-1}{t\ln{t}}=\lim_{t\to 1}\dfrac{1}{t}\cdot\lim_{t\to 1}\dfrac{t-1}{\ln{t}}=\lim_{t\to 1}\dfrac{t-1}{\ln{t}}$$
$$\lim_{t\to 1}t-1=\lim_{t\to 1}\ln{t}=0$$
Apply L'Hôpital's rule and differentiate both terms separately:
$$\lim_{t\to 1}\dfrac{1}{\ln{t}}-\dfrac{1}{t\ln{t}}=\lim_{t\to 1}\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{t}}=\lim_{t\to 1}t=1$$

Comment: I know how to calculate this limit, the other one is the problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry then. I support `mickep`'s answer.